# OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow

My tensorflow version is 2.4.0-rc0.

Afer I debug my code, my code seems have one problem as below:

```
@tf.function
    def keypoint_distance(self, kpt):
        if kpt[2] == tf.constant(0.0):
            return tf.ones((self.LABEL_HEIGHT, self.LABEL_WIDTH), dtype=tf.float32)
        else:
            ortho_dist = self.grid - kpt[0:2]
            return tf.linalg.norm(ortho_dist, axis=-1)
```

Where did I treat a Tensor as a bool?

The all message I get：

```
raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Python `bool` in graph mode. You should instead use [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond). It will return a function depending on a condition.

```
import tensorflow as tf


@tf.function
def keypoint_distance(kpt):
    return tf.cond(pred=kpt[2] == tf.constant(0.0),
                   true_fn=lambda: tf.ones((3, 4), dtype=tf.float32),
                   false_fn=lambda: tf.linalg.norm(kpt[0:2], axis=-1))


keypoint_distance([1., 2., 3.])  # will be false
keypoint_distance([1., 2., 0.])  # will be true
```

Note that I removed objects that weren't defined in your code sample.

Comment: It works! I have another question. How can I add one condition in pred like:  pred=(kpt[2] == tf.constant(0.0) or kpt[2] == tf.constant(1.1))  ?@Nicolas Gervais

Comment: Use `tf.logical_and(condition1, condition2)`

Comment: Thanks!  If there are many statements to insert in the if statement, is there any ways to solve it?

Comment: Yes, you can have as many conditions in `tf.logical_and()`. Try `tf.logical_and(True, True, True)`. But we're getting off topic, if your issue was solved I suggest you mark this answer as accepted, and ask any other question in a new post!